# How to export collections counter to CSV file with good format

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Here is my code:

```
from collections import Counter

print("Enter/Paste your content. Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z ( windows ) to save it.")
contents = []
def amount():
    while True:
        try:
            line = input()
        except EOFError:
            break
        contents.append(line)

    return
amount()


count = Counter(contents)
print(count)
```

When you enter a number or numbers into this, let's say 3, 4 and 5, it will come printed out in this format:

```
Counter({'3': 1, '4': 1, '5': 1})
```

I was wondering if it were possible to export this into a CSV file but have it formatted as anything like this:

```
Column 1  Column 2
3:            1
4:            1
5:            1
```

Comment: Did you do any research? "Python CSV" should bring up https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html pretty promptly.

Comment: note, that isn't really a csv...

Comment: @jonrsharpe i have done some research and done some programs using CSV files but I cannot seem to get this one to format how I want it to.

Comment: So show _those_ programs, but `print`ing a `Counter` certainly isn't going to give you the output you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can with `Pandas`. I'm Just mentioning Myu way to do it...

```
from collections import Counter

print("Enter/Paste your content. Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z ( windows ) to save it.")
contents = []
def amount():
    while True:
        try:
            line = input()
        except EOFError:
            break
        contents.append(line)

    return
amount()


count = Counter(contents)
print(count)

import pandas as pd
d = count
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').reset_index()
df.columns =['column1', 'colum2']

df = df.sort_values(by=['column1'],ascending=False)

print(df)
df.to_csv("camo1.csv", encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

#output Csv

[image]

Comment: It works! If possible, I was wondering in addition to this if pandas is capable of sorting information by Greatest ---> Least. For example, lets say the counter found 5 instances of there being a  2 in the input, would it be possible for that to be the first thing that shows up on the excel file and then have it descend from there?

Comment: Yeah, we can..I just modified the code

Comment: :) Anytime.....